# Given a directory containing say a few thousand files, please output a list of all the names of the files in the directory that are exactly the same

Tags: python, bash, shell, groovy

, i.e. have the same contents.

func(a_directory_name) output -> {“matches”: [[fn1, fn2 …], [fn3, fn4 …] … ]}

e.g. func(“/home/my/files”) where the directory /home/my/files might contain foo.txt, foo.iso, foo.jpeg, bar.txt, bar.doc, baz.csv, baz.ppt etc. and say the file foo.txt is the same as bar.doc and foo.iso is the same as baz.csv and baz.ppt then the output would be:

{

```
"matches": [

    [

        "foo.txt",

        "bar.doc"

    ],

    [

        "foo.iso",

        "baz.csv",

        “baz.ppt”

    ]

]
```

}

You may code the response in any programming language you like

PS. I tried hashing,

[Please check what I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnSWV.png)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: Just trying to get some help mate! stuck with this from quite a long time. Sorry to offend you.

Comment: @Craig in that case, perhaps show us some of your attempts, and we can figure out why it's not working?

Comment: You need to show what you’ve tried and what doesn’t work. Something like a minimal complete verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: No offense taken. Welcome to StackOverflow! Read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get responses. You can also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @Alex Thanks! Just getting started with StackOverflow. I am just a High school student. Will learn. :)

Comment: @sacul Updated the question with what I tried, Please check. I tried hashing

Comment: @Pam Attached a image to the question, I tried doing that, Please check!

Comment: Can you paste actual code into the question? Screenshots of code are effectively useless. Also, in what way didn't your attempt work?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is what you're looking for...  In Groovy at least:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import java.security.MessageDigest

def folderOfInterest = args[0]

println "Grouping by content for files in ${folderOfInterest}"

def result = new File(folderOfInterest)
    .listFiles({ f -> f.file } as FileFilter)
    .collectEntries { f ->
        [f.name, MessageDigest.getInstance('MD5').with { d ->
            f.eachByte(4096) {
                b, len -> d.update(b, 0, len)
            }
            d.digest().encodeHex().toString()
        }]
    }
    .groupBy { it.value }
    .collect { it.value.keySet() }
    .findAll { it.size() > 1 }

println new JsonBuilder(result).toPrettyString()
```

Save it as `Group.groovy` then run it with `groovy Group.groovy /path/to/directory`